# Can anyone recognize this glyph or ligature?

Tags: graphemics

Can anyone recognize this glyph or ligature?

[image: unkown glyph]

For context, it appears on the [entry for "alquimia"](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/765/156/tesoro-de-la-lengua-castellana-o-espanola/) in Covarrubias' *Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española*, published in 1611.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This barred q is one of the abbreviations for any one of many Latin words beginning with q, among them the super common relative pronoun "[qui, quae, quod](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui#Latin)", which would apply in this case (as the neuter gender form *quod*, as seen in full [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QJ9tPQGiSIsC&pg=PA327&lpg=PA327&dq=%22significat%20facere%20ambulare%22&source=bl&ots=x4s0rkODfI&sig=IAVKdwtUNMUbamdx0jVbJ_HijOI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vMfYVNyFA4j97AbqlYCQCg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22significat%20facere%20ambulare%22&f=false)).

Comment: Thanks! There's even a unicode character for it: ꝗ (q with stroke): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_with_stroke

Answer (score 2):

This ligature stands for *quae*. Here is a modern type [transliteration of that sentence](https://www.academia.edu/5087940/La_Qu%C3%ADmica_del_1600_seg%C3%BAn_el_Tesoro_Lexicogr%C3%A1fico) with the ligature, it is below the image of the page:

> "Etenim alchim signiﬁcat itinera sive ﬂuxus ab alich, **quae** signiﬁcat facere, ambulare, seu ﬂuere, unde ars liquans seu fundens metalla abiecta literula, i, ﬁt alquimia facillima formatione", etc.

[Another source](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=5wSAQvmi9i4C&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=%22Etenim%20alchim,%20significat%20itinera%22&source=bl&ots=Nh_aGRBORn&sig=3e4fdyR87G5NJd4d2XeNgNJCubw&hl=uk&sa=X&ei=UsnYVJr3NIPnygPUhIDwDg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Etenim%20alchim%2C%20significat%20itinera%22&f=false) with the same tranliteration.

Comment: "quod" is correct, "quae" is wrong in this context.